# Possibly corrupted DAG file

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethminer, dag, shares

I've started mining on Ubuntu 16.04 using AMD-GPU PRO driver and this miner:

https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/

Video card is a RX480 with 8GB stock.

I'm getting a lot of bad shares, like 10% to 20% are bad shares, on Minergate pool.

A quick search on internet says that this is caused by a corrupted DAG file, and says it is under $(HOME)/.ethash/ and removing it will solve the problem.

But this folder does not exist. I've checked both on root and my user, there's no such folder. I've even tried using a find to check if this folder is anywhere in the system, but it does not exist at all.

Does this miner stores DAG file on other folder?

Thanks in advance.